# Axios retornando HTML de dados, não JSON

Tags: json, node.js, react, get, axios

Estou desenvolvendo pequeno projeto para aprender react e me deparei com o seguinte problema.
Ao fazer uma solicitação em uma API com axios passando o input como parametro para a rota, o axios está retornando um HTML, e não um JSON.

O link do repositório caso ajude.
https://github.com/carlos-souza-dev/apinews

Esse é meu código.

```js
  // REACT
  
  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');
  const [ query, setQuery ] = useState([]);
  
  const queryFunc = async () => {
    setQuery( await axios.get(`${props.url}/search`).then(res => {
        console.log("Response",res)
        return res.data.articles
      }))
    };

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    axios.get(`${props.url}/search`, {
      text: input,      
    });
  };
  
  
  // ROUTER
  
  app.get('/api/brasil/search', async  (req, res) => {

  const text = await ""+req.body.text;
  
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_URL}top-headlines?q=${text}&country=pt&from=${today}&to=${today}&apiKey=${process.env.APP_KEY}&pageSize=100`);
  const data = await response.json();
  res.send(data)
});
```

Esta é a response do axios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O _axios_ apenas traz o que ele recebe como resposta do endpoint. O que esse endpoint `http://localhost:5000/api/search` está trazendo? Não seria ele o problema?

Comment: O problema não é no AXIOS neste caso, provavelmente vc está fazendo a requisição para um Website e não para uma API. Experimente com outras "APIs", por exemplo, https://fakerapi.it/en é uma API muito utilizada para testar aplicações. Abraço! Sucesso!

Comment: Eu quero enviar um palavra como pesquisa para a rota, então, eu criei uma rota "http://localhost:5000/api/search" e nessa rota é feito o fetch em uma API e retorna os dados "res.send(resposta.data)" para a rota "/search" e no componente eu pego essa rota "http://localhost:5000/api/search" e uso o axios para trazer a resposta, e aí que acontece o problema.
Quando eu coloco a palavra direto na url da api funciona perfeitamente, agora se eu coloco a palavra através de uma variável não funciona.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, com um [mcve] do problema no lugar do código atual. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).